# Erro 91 using while with Cells.Find

Tags: vb.net, while-loop

I started using VB recently. The objective is to find the word "Data" and delete the two rows in the front and 5 rows behind.

But ended up with an error. Please correct me.

```
While Cells.Find(What:="Data", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Fnd = ActiveCell.Row
Frm = Fnd - 2
Too = Fnd + 5
Rows(Frm & ":" & Too).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Cells(Frm, 1).Select
Wend
```

Please correct me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to check in the entire grid for `data`? you want to delete rows or columns?

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply.
 
Yes I wanted to search all the rows. "Data" is available in first column but appears in many rows. I wanted to delete the rows around the row that has "Data".

Comment: ie., you want to delete the particular row if the first column contains "data", isn't it?

Comment: Yes!.Actuall the code works correctly and does the job. However, It is giving error after the last occurrence of the "Data".